# Showing String in Grafana Graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grafana

I am play with Grafana, reading some metrics from a Rails app, just for test propose.

My data is something like that:

```
 {:endpoint=>"POST_ItemsController#create", :duration=>2938.779, :view_runtime=>2901.051}
```

But I don't know how (if is possible) show the endpoint name in the Graph, my query:

```
SELECT "duration", "endpoint" FROM "endpoint_stats" WHERE $timeFilter
```

And the result:

[image]

String are not supported here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you are not setting the endpoint name as tag and use Alias by ?

Comment: Hi @MarkB I will look it. Thanks

Comment: you can also check it out here: http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-templated-queries This dashboard uses templating but your usecase would be the same

Comment: Hi @MarkB it works. Thanks

Comment: glad I was able to help you! I posted my comments as a final answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up my comments: You can archive this by saving the endpoint name as **tag** and using `Alias By(..)`. See the following a screenshot from grafana play:

[image] [Source](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-templated-queries)